# Should I put a hyphen in “sans-serif”?

Tags: fonts, terminology

If i am describing a font and i say «it is a sans serif» should i put a hyphen in sans-serif or not? A random amount of googling suggests that both with- and without-hyphen are used, and each one often by a respected authority.

Are there any well documented guidelines?

I'm well aware that many style-guides would recommend a hyphen when “sans serif” is used as an adjective, in for example «the headline should use a sans-serif font», but i'm not really talking about that case.

Comment: This is probably cultural. A Brit would hyphenate in many more circumstances than an American would. Neither is right or wrong, merely stylistic.

Comment: sure, i guess. my question is "are there any well documented guidelines?".

Comment: As you didn't hyphenate well-documented, I guess you should be looking at US-based resources ;)) To a Brit, it sounds odd - imagine the difference, to take a modern cultural filler word 'like'… "Are there any like-minded individuals?" vs. "Are there any, like, minded individuals?" The US un-hyphenated version sounds [reads] like the comma-separated version to a Brit ;))

Comment: haha. i was going to make the same point about finding, well, documented guidelines after you raised the matter.

Comment: This could turn into a long joke thread [long-joke… long, joke…] if we're not careful, so I'll try my best not to ;)) I don't know of any specific resources, so I'll leave it to the professionals. Wish you luck, all the best :)

Comment: I think this is far more a preference of the writer's voice (and possibly location). I do *not* think serif/san-serif matters in this instance.